# restricting access to pages php

Tags: php

In my website after user logs in, I would like to restric access to certain pages based on user id stored in $_SESSION['user_id'] and redirect users that didnt logged in to difrent url:pleaselogin.php ? how to check if user is logged in then can stay else redirect to diferent url
I have logeed users stored in $_session['user_id'] how to redirect     not logged users to another page ?

Comment: Please post what you've already tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    header('Location: pleaselogin.php')
```

It should be noted that `header()` will only work if you haven't already sent content back in the request. So that should be the first thing you do before returning *any* data. Check out the PHP manual on `header()` for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: and noted it should be a full URI not a relative one.